# What's the most popular manga rating site for the Japanese readership?

Tags: japanese-language, resources

I'm thinking something along the lines of [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/) but it does not have to include anime per se. I'm just interested to see how some series are viewed among the Japanese fanbase.

If there isn't a clear "most popular" site, a list of the common ones would suffice.

I am aware of [anikore](https://www.anikore.jp/), but that's more for anime though.

Comment: To my knowledge, there are no such sites. Usually they are gauged by sales e.g. like [Oricon](https://www.oricon.co.jp/rank/obc/w/2022-12-12/). Note this is (naturally) by-volume basis.